# How do I expose entity ids in a mutiple datasource project?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My project talks to at least two databases with the requirement that entity ids be exposed. I've tried most solutions online but kept getting this error: `Field manager in ... required a single bean, but 2 were found:...`
How do I achieve this requirement using this simplified config class?

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={...}
public class MyConfig{
@Autowired
private EntityManager manager;
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.akad")
public DataSourceProperties akadDataSourceProps(){
return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Primary
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.akad")
public DataSource akaData(){
return akadDataSourceProps().initialzeDataSourceBuilder.type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = "akadEntityFac")
public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean akaFact(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder build){

String [] packgesToScan = {...};

return builder.datasource(akad()).packagesToScan).build();
}

@Primary
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager akadMan("akadEntityFac") LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean akadManFac){

return JpaTransactionManager(akadManFac.getObject());

//this method below throws the error
@Primary
public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors){
config.exposeIdsFor(manager.getMetaModel().getEntities().stream().map(Type::getJavaType).toArray(Class[]::new));
}

//If I comment the last method, the error would be cleared but the entity ids wouldn't get exposed.
}
```